# HTML form with $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, html, forms

I've just finished setting up AMP on a new MacOS El Capitan installation with all the steps listed in the [Coolest Guide](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/).

I have a simple HTML/PHP form that I used to run in my previous MacOS installation without any problems and I can't get it to work now:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$link = $_POST['link']; 
echo $name; 
echo $post; 
echo $link; 
echo "all good";
} 
?>

<form name="upload" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
   Name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   Post:<br>
   <input type="text" name="post"><br>
   Link:<br>
   <input type="text" name="link"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

Whenever I run the HTML form I now see (method="post">) right before the three text boxes! And when I hit the submit button I get a 404 error "The requested URL /~Eduardo/< was not found on this server."

Is there something I need to enable on this installation that it's not detailed on that web page?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: shows whether your form on the page URL /~Eduardo/ ?
if yes,see your htaccess

Comment: yes, I can see my form on that URL...I only get the 404 error when I hit submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes arround php tag and single quotes for $_SERVER  key

```
  <form name="upload" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: That's better! I now see the form as it should be. However...

"The requested URL /~Eduardo/< was not found on this server."

...when I hit the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the content of the `action` attribute of your form. Like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"...
```

Comment: I've tried that as well...

<form name="upload" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">

and now I get this when running the HTML form:

" method="post">

followed by the 3 text boxes...

Comment: I don't see any difference between code in your question and your comment. You're still missing the quotes `"`.

Comment: Weird. What is in the page source?

Comment: Copy-paste the page source where is the <form> element (Ctrl+U usually).

Comment: too long for a comment so I deleted the php config from this comment. The page source is:

<form name="upload" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
   Name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   Post:<br>
   <input type="text" name="post"><br>
   Link:<br>
   <input type="text" name="link"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>